# как лучше сделать в php сервере?

Tags: php, c

Например я хочу сделать игровой сервер на php. он будет обрабатывать запросы и отправлять ответы в json формате. я сначала подумал что будет код прикольно смотреться, если сделать чтобы все запросы перенаправлялись в один файл index.php. а в нем уже идет проверка маршрута и подключение нужных файлов. но я думаю что в этом есть проблема. пока он обработает каждый маршрут, чтобы узнать какие файлы подключать. будет нагрузка на сервер. но если сделать чтобы каждый файл отвечал сам за себя, то эта нагрузка пропадает. Как лучше делать? Ответьте пожалуйста по этому поводу. а также кто хочет, может сказать, что может лучше сделать сервер на си?

Comment: php лучше использовать для тех целей, для которых он предназначен. Не знаю конечно архитектуру Вашего игрового сервера, но как правило там нужен постоянный конект, где лучше использовать другие модели. А если вопрос производительности, то это далеко не самый критичный фактор, на старте.

Comment: Упадет, но не настолько критично, чтрбы жертвовать удобством разработки

Comment: @EvgeniiIzhboldin там клиент на unity webgl. постоянного коннекта не требуется. нужно лишь только отправить запрос и получить ответ, чтобы нарисовать в webgl результат.

Comment: И в каждом файле будет что - `include 'mysql_connect.php'`?

Comment: @u_mulder и чего в этом плохого?

Comment: @u_mulder нет, будет не подключение, а логин, пароль, данные для подключения. подключение будет в файле производиться уже.

Comment: Ну если не нужно постоянного коннекта, то чего не взять фреймворк и не написать просто уже стандартную mvc структуру, оставить только api контроллер с json ответом, и не придумывать велосипедов, потом и масштабирование можно заложить в перспективе.

Comment: @EvgeniiIzhboldin фреймворк не нужен. у меня есть свои классы роутинга со статическими методами как в laravel. больше ничего такого не нужно и не нужно тащить эти кучу зависимостей и нагружать проект. там всего то нужен роутинг, работа с бд и отправка ответа. нафига здесь фреймворк?

Comment: Внесу свои 5 копеек. Если ваша игра будет общаться с сервером крайне редко, то можно использовать и php с фреймворком (лучше вариант микро, для уменьшения числа компонентов). Тут фреймворк не внесёт существенную задержку, зато очень сильно повлияет на легкость поддержки кода. Если же ваша игра общается с сервером очень часто, то вам не обойтись без многопоточного обработчика событий с уровнями приоритета. Воротить такое на php сущее извращение.

Comment: Вот, соглашусь с @ArchDemon, фреймворк это не только куча зависимостей, но и станадртизация, что бы потом не приходилось с болью вспоминать какая структура была придумана :-) Боитесь большого фреймворка, можно взять микро, silex, lumen и прочие